# Connect to other users Outlook in Azure Logic App

Tags: outlook, office365, azure-logic-apps, office365connectors, azure-logic-app-standard

I have constructed a LogicApp Standard that manipulates Outlook Tasks. The "Outlook Tasks Connector" allows me to nominate an account to use when doing this, but the Actions only give me access to that account's Task Lists.

How do I go about creating a LogicApp Standard that manipulates Outlook Tasks (and Calendar etc.) for a user defined at runtime by a parameter ? Is there a different Connector or Action I should be using for this ?

Comment: Use the HTTP connector with the relevant Graph endpoints. Are you sure you can’t change the connection on each action? I haven’t looked if you can.

Comment: The Outlook Tasks Create API in Graph is now deprecated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp . 

The replacement ToDo does seem to support the POST to a UPN (rather than just Me) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 

Thank you for pointing me at the Graph AP- I will roll my own connector using that. If you want to post your reply as an Answer I'll happily mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to change the connection action on action then your best bet is to look at using the relevant Graph API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

It will allow you to adjust the parameters rather than relying on a single connection.